# Merging hexagons in layer to create multiple polygons of equal size using QGIS?

Tags: qgis, mmqgis, cartogram

I'm trying to create a hexagon cartogram of electoral constituencies for Pakistan in QGIS. I've got a shapefile of Pakistan's boundaries and I've loaded a layer of overlapping hexagons on top using the MMQGIS plugin. Now I want to merge the hexagons into 272 polygons consisting of equal number of hexagons.

I want to keep the overall shape of the country intact, so any remaining polygons that cannot be added should be lying on the outer boundaries so I can keep the overall shape close to the shape of the country without any gaps in between.

[image: Hexagon grid clipped to shape of country]

The above example image shows a couple of hexagons manually merged into polygons. I want all 272 polygons to comprise of an equal number of hexagons each. How can I do this in QGIS?